# I Keep getting "SDK tools directory is missing" Error during Android Studio Setup

Tags: android-studio

I tried to uninstall my existing android studio and to make it clean I also deleted all the android directories including the "android" folder inside the "user/AppData/Local" directory where the sdk folder existed.

And now when I try to make a new installation, I get an error "SDK tools directory is missing" and there is no folder named "android" inside the "user/AppData/Local" directory. What should I do to create this folder?

Comment: what is your OS? Mac or Linux? Please add the details to your question.

Comment: It's Windows 10.

Comment: Have you cleanly uninstall all the Android studio from Program Files, Both in x86 and x64 Program Files directory?